# Using matrices for a recurrence to compute $a_n$ in $O(\log n)$

Tags: matrices, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

How would I compute $a_n$ in $O(\log n)$ given they have a linear recurrence, such as $a_i=3b_{i-1}+2b_{i-2}+6^i, b_i=14a_{i-1}-b_{i-2}-6^i$ with matrices?

I know how to deal with recurrences like  $a_i=b_0a_{i-1}+b_1a_{i-2}+\cdots+b_ka_{i-k-1}$ in $O(k^3 \log n)$

Dealing with constants isn’t hard; for $a_i=3a_{i-1}+2a_{i-2}+1$, I can let $b_i=a_i-\frac 14$ to clear the constant term.

I don't know how to deal with an exponential term and multiple sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Look at new sequences $A_i = \frac{a_i}{6^i}$ and $B_i = \frac{b_i}{6^i}$. By dividing your original recurrences by $6^i$, we see that these must satisfy the following recurrences:

$$
A_i = \frac{3 B_{i-1}}{6} + \frac{2 B_{i-2}}{6^2} + 1 
\quad \quad 
B_i = \frac{14 A_{i-1}}{6} - \frac{B_{i-2}}{6^2} -1
$$

From here, standard matrix theoretic techniques will work. After finding the $A_i$ and $B_i$, you can recover $a_i = 6^i A_i$ and $b_i = 6^i B_i$.

As an aside, though -- $a_n$ will *not* be $O(\log(n))$. In fact, $a_i$ seems to grow extremely quickly (proof by [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/)):

[image: a sage plot of a_i]

---

**Edit:**

I realize I misunderstood your question - you don't want to show that $a_n \in O(\log(n))$. Instead you want to compute $a_n$ in $O(\log(n))$ time by using the [repeated squaring trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

While you could still use the trick of $A_i$ and $B_i$ to turn our recurrence into something more manageable, we can also do the whole problem in one step:

We want to work with $a_i$ and $b_i$, and to compute them we need to keep track of $a_{i-1}$, $b_{i-1}$, and $b_{i-2}$.

So we package this data into a vector, and want to find a matrix $M$ so that the following holds:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_i\\ b_i\\ a_{i-1}\\ b_{i-1}\\ 6^i \end{pmatrix}
=
M
\begin{pmatrix} a_{i-1}\\ b_{i-1}\\ a_{i-2}\\ b_{i-2}\\ 6^{i-1} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Notice we keep a $6^i$ in our vector because we need it in order to compute the future $a_i$.

If we find such a matrix $M$, then notice $a_n$ is just the first entry of $M^n v$ for some vector of initial conditions $v$ (why?). We can then use the repeated squaring trick to compute $M^n$ (and thus $a_n$) efficiently.

Do you see how to construct such a matrix $M$? Hint: The $a_i$ and $b_i$ are given as linear combinations of earlier $a$s and $b$s, as well as a $6^i$, all of which we're keeping track of in the vector!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! A few comments: I am computing $a_i$ in O(log n), $a_i$ is exponential. To finish, we just clear the constant term and write b_i in terms of a_i?

Comment: Oooooooh. I misunderstood, haha. Yeah - you can compute $a_n$ in $O(\log(n))$ time by using repeated squaring of matrices. I wouldn't write $b_i$ in terms of $a_i$ - you can just have a matrix that keeps track of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I'll add a word about this to my answer

Comment: Here, $M=[[0,3,0,2,6],[14,0,0,-1,6],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,6]]$.